# Bootstrap button and Paypal button same size

Tags: reactjs, button, bootstrap-4, styled-components, paypal-buttons

Is there a way to make the two buttons of the same size?
Also possibly when the page is resized?
I noticed that the paypal button, when the page is resized, changes its height.

It would be great if the two buttons had the same width 50%/50% compared to the external div and fixed height of 55px.

**Thank you in advance!**

**My page:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'moment/locale/it'
import moment from 'moment'
import $ from 'jquery';
import { Row, Col, Form, Button, FloatingLabel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Pagamento, PagamentoH1, PagamentoWrapper } from './PagamentoElements';
import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

const PagamentoPage = () => {

    const { state } = useLocation();
    const [informations, setInformations] = useState('');
    const [stringPrice, setStringPrice] = useState('');
    const price = useRef();

    const initialOptions = {
        "client-id": "AVtisWaj3Lp4WwN6_vTYC4tmijgunLVMnbtN_7Nb7Mc0tZoThBGS9XPcGLY4jYYTeuEE6Z6u__WSHjpD",
        components: "buttons",
        currency: "EUR"
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getInformations() {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                           'Authorization': sessionStorage.getItem("tokenType") + " " + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken") },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "id": state.idChoice
                })
            };
    
            let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/getUser", requestOptions);
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            setInformations(responseJson);
            let newStartDate = moment(state.startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            let newEndDate = moment(state.endDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            const dateStart = new Date(newStartDate);
            const endDate = new Date(newEndDate);
            const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            const diffInTime = endDate.getTime() - dateStart.getTime();
            const diffInDays = Math.round(diffInTime / oneDay);
            price.current = (parseInt(diffInDays) * parseFloat(responseJson['prezzo']));
            setStringPrice((parseInt(diffInDays) * parseFloat(responseJson['prezzo'])).toFixed(2) + "€");
            if (responseJson['nomeStruttura'] != null) {
                $("#formStruttura").css("display", "block");
                $("#textNomeStruttura").val(responseJson['nomeStruttura']);
                $("#labelNome").text('Nome del titolare');
                $("#labelCognome").text('Cognome del titolare');
                $("#textNome").val(responseJson['nome']);
                $("#textCognome").val(responseJson['cognome']);
            } else {
                $("#formStruttura").css("display", "none");
                $("#labelNome").text('Nome del Petsitter');
                $("#labelCognome").text('Cognome del Petsitter');
                $("#textNome").val(responseJson['nome']);
                $("#textCognome").val(responseJson['cognome']);
                $("#pOnl").css("display", "none");
                $("#pCont").text("Conferma e paga direttamente al Petsitter");
                $("#pCont").css("margin-right", "0");
            }
            if (state.cure === null) {
                $("#divCure").css("display", "none");
            }
            if (state.socievole === null) {
                $("#divSoc").css("display", "none");
            }
        }
        getInformations().catch(err => console.log(err));
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])


    const handleSubmitPayment = (orderId) => {
        console.log(state.cure);
        console.log(state.socievole);
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       'Authorization': sessionStorage.getItem("tokenType") + " " + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken") },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "user_id": state.idChoice,
                "startDate": state.startDate,
                "endDate": state.endDate,
                "prezzo": price.current,
                "cure": state.cure,
                "socievole": state.socievole,
                "transactionId": orderId
            })
        };
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/reservations/save", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data['message'].includes('Reservation registered successfully!')) {
                console.log("Prenotazione salvata!");
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Pagamento>
                <PagamentoH1>Resoconto e pagamento</PagamentoH1>
                <Form>
                    <PagamentoWrapper>
                        <Row className="mb-4">
                            <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>Data di inizio</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" value={state.startDate} readOnly={true}></Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>Data di fine</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" value={state.endDate} readOnly={true}></Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Row>
                        <Row className="mb-4">
                            <Form.Group id="formStruttura" style={{display: "none"}} as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label id="labelNomeStruttura">Nome Struttura</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control id="textNomeStruttura" type="text"  readOnly={true}></Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label id="labelNome"></Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control id="textNome" type="text"  readOnly={true}></Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label id="labelCognome"></Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control id="textCognome" type="text"  readOnly={true}></Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Row>
                        <Row className="mb-4">
                            <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>Indirizzo della struttura</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" value={informations['indirizzo'] + ", " + informations['citta'] + ", " + informations['cap']} readOnly={true}></Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Row>
                        <Row className="mb-4">
                            <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>Telefono</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" value={informations['telefono']} readOnly={true}></Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Row>
                        <div id="divCure">
                            <Form.Label>Dettagli sulle cure</Form.Label>
                            <FloatingLabel className="mb-4" style={{color: "#999"}} label="Dettagli">
                                <Form.Control readOnly={true} type="text" value={state.cure} placeholder="Dettagli" />
                            </FloatingLabel >
                        </div>
                        <div id="divSoc">
                            <Form.Label>Dettagli sulla socialità</Form.Label>
                            <FloatingLabel className="mb-4" style={{color: "#999"}} label="Dettagli">
                                <Form.Control readOnly={true} type="text" value={state.socievole} placeholder="Dettagli" />
                            </FloatingLabel>
                        </div>
                        <Row className="mb-5">
                            <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                <Form.Label>Totale da pagare</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control id="textPrice" type="text" value={stringPrice} readOnly={true}></Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Row>
                        <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                            <div className='btn-group'>
                                <Button id="pCont" variant="primary" style={{height: "55px", marginBottom: "40px"}} onClick={() => {
                                    handleSubmitPayment(null);
                                }}>Conferma e paga in contanti</Button>
                                <PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>
                                    <PayPalButtons 
                                        onApprove={async function (data, actions) {
                                            await actions.order.capture();
                                            handleSubmitPayment(data.orderID);
                                        }} 
                                        createOrder={(data, actions) => {
                                            return actions.order
                                                .create({
                                                    purchase_units: [
                                                        {
                                                            amount: {
                                                                description: "PetCare Paypal Payment",
                                                                currency_code: "EUR",
                                                                value: price.current,
                                                            },
                                                        },
                                                    ],
                                                })
                                        }}
                                        style={{ layout: "horizontal"}} 
                                    />
                                </PayPalScriptProvider>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </PagamentoWrapper>
                </Form>
            </Pagamento>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PagamentoPage
```

**PagamentoElements.js:**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Pagamento = styled.div`
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #010606;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
`

export const PagamentoH1 = styled.h1`
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
`

export const PagamentoWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 40px;
    color: #fff;

    @media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
        width: 45%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 968px) {
        width: 60%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        width: 80%;
    }
`
```